# QML QWebView with non resizing content

Tags: html, qt, qwebview, qtquick2

I use Qt Quick 2.2 and QML WebView 3.0. My application has fixed size areas that should display HTML inside them (mostly text and images, no complex layouts, no JS, no CSS). I write the HTML myself. The HTML content should not scroll horizontally and not be scaled but the text re-layouted to fit the width as browsers usually do.

Opening http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daft_Punk in a normal web browser shows the behavior I want (text being re-layouted according to the width).

This minimal code example shows the behavior I have and don't want, it scales the Website and leaves the layout untouched.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtWebKit 3.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    WebView {
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daft_Punk"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? If not, are there obvious alternatives to QWebView for displaying images and layouted text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QML WebView seems to be designed for small screens like phones, and as such it rescales the entire page to fit the width.

Fortunately there is an undocumented workaround to this: set a small preferred minimum width to make the scaling trigger at a smaller size.  The downside is that this has unwanted side effects if you resize the window below this minimum.

Here's your example with the preferred minimum workaround:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0 // Use QtWebKit's experimental features

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    WebView {
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daft_Punk"
        anchors.fill: parent
        experimental.preferredMinimumContentsWidth: 300 // Set the min width
    }
}
```